# Digital Signature Appearance appearance

Tags: ios, podofo

I was able to produce an invisible digital signature using
PoDoFo. It is correctly recognized and verified by adobe reader.

Now I
have to add an appearance to the related annotation to make it visible.

I'm carefully following the abode directives described here:

http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/acrobat_digital_signature_appearances_v9.pdf

I added the needed XObjects as explained there but I wasn't able to
make it visible. I always see a blank rectangle with nothing inside.

It's making me crazy.

Please, does someone know how to add an
appearance to a digital signature using podofo?